# How to debug my country>states>cities code so it displays states and cities?

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var countries = from country in xdoc.Descendants("countries").Elements("country").Attributes("name")
                    select country.Value;
    comboBox_country.DataSource = countries.ToList()
}

private void comboBox_country_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var states = from country in xdoc.Descendants("countries").Elements("country")
                 where country.Attribute("name").Value == comboBox_country.SelectedValue
                 select country;

    var s = from state in states.Elements("state")
            select state.Value;
    comboBox_state.DataSource = s.ToList();
}

private void comboBox_state_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cities = from state in xdoc.Descendants("state").Elements("state")
                 where state.Attribute("name").Value == comboBox_state.SelectedValue
                 select state;

    var c = from city in cities.Elements("city")
            select city.Value;
           comboBox_city.DataSource = c.ToList();
}
```

Where do I need to do modifications?

I am trying to select countries related to states and related cities. I've created an XML file and trying to read from that XML file into a win form layout which has countries state city as labels and corresponding combo boxes.

Comment: could you provide the structure of the xml file you work with.

Comment: didn't get what is your issue? Are you saying while selecting Country dropdown selectedIndexchange of State is not hitting or from xml file you want to upload the selected data in form?

Comment: You may want to add a few more `.ToList()`. Then add breakpoints to your "selectedIndexChanged" methods and inspect the resulting lists - do they contain the values you expected?